How to add icon to menubar items?
const editorInitConfig = {
  // ...
  menubar: "file edit view insert format table custom",
  menu: {
    // ...
    custom: {
      // icon: "emoji", this option does not exist
      title: "Custom",
      items: "...",
    },
  },
  // ...
};


I've tried some custom injection to no prevail, I attempted to inject an SVG after the editor initializes on the page.

The title and items are the only properties supported by a menu option. It's neither recommended nor reliable to override the editor CSS rules, but it is possible.
For example, the third (custom) item of
{
  menubar: "file edit custom"
}

can be selected using .tox-menubar .tox-mbtn:nth-of-type(3) and the svg background can be set for its span label:
.tox-menubar .tox-mbtn:nth-of-type(3) > span:first-child {
  padding-left: 24px;
  background: 0 center no-repeat url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
}

Using a current TinyMCE 7 the modified menu should look similar to:


.tox-menubar {
  font-size: 0;
}

.tox-mbtn {
  font: 14px sans-serif;
  background: white;
  padding: 0 4px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 28px;
}

.tox-mbtn:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}

.tox-mbtn:active {
  background: #a6ccf7;
}

.tox-mbtn__select-chevron {
  display: none;
}

.tox-menubar .tox-mbtn:nth-of-type(3)>span:first-child {
  padding-left: 24px;
  background: 0 center no-repeat url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMjAiIGhlaWdodD0iMjAiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA2NCA2NCIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj48Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSIzMiIgY3k9IjMyIiByPSIyNy43NTgiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOiNmOWJmNDQiLz48cGF0aCBkPSJNMzIgNDUuMTY1YTEyLjU4IDEyLjU4IDAgMCAxLTExLjM2OC03LjA3OSAxIDEgMCAxIDEgMS43OTUtLjg4MiAxMC42NjcgMTAuNjY3IDAgMCAwIDE5LjE0NiAwIDEgMSAwIDEgMSAxLjc5NS44ODJBMTIuNTggMTIuNTggMCAwIDEgMzIgNDUuMTY1IiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDojMzgyYTEyIi8+PGVsbGlwc2UgY3g9IjIxLjAwMyIgY3k9IjI5Ljc0NSIgcng9IjIuNSIgcnk9IjIuODciIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOiMzODJhMTIiLz48ZWxsaXBzZSBjeD0iNDIuOTk3IiBjeT0iMjkuNzQ1IiByeD0iMi41IiByeT0iMi44NyIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6IzM4MmExMiIvPjwvc3ZnPg==");
}
<div role="menubar" data-alloy-tabstop="true" class="tox-menubar">
  <button aria-haspopup="true" role="menuitem" type="button" tabindex="-1" data-alloy-tabstop="true" unselectable="on" class="tox-mbtn tox-mbtn--select" style="user-select: none; width: 37.95px;" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="tox-mbtn__select-label">File</span>
    <div class="tox-mbtn__select-chevron">...</div>
  </button>
  <button aria-haspopup="true" role="menuitem" type="button" tabindex="-1" data-alloy-tabstop="true" unselectable="on" class="tox-mbtn tox-mbtn--select" style="user-select: none; width: 39.7167px;" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="tox-mbtn__select-label">Edit</span>
    <div class="tox-mbtn__select-chevron">...</div>
  </button>
  <button aria-haspopup="true" role="menuitem" type="button" tabindex="-1" data-alloy-tabstop="true" unselectable="on" class="tox-mbtn tox-mbtn--select" style="user-select: none; width: 88.7833px;" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="tox-mbtn__select-label">Custom</span>
    <div class="tox-mbtn__select-chevron">...</div>
  </button>
</div>




This works well, of course overriding the editor CSS is not reliable like you mentioned, but a decent suggestion until it is an incorporated feature.... which it should be.
